# How to Ensure a String has no digits

Tags: java, string

I have a string and want to make sure it does not contain digits. Is there a method in the String library that does it or i have to implement it myself?

Comment: You can have a look at matches with a regexp

Comment: @AlexisC.: oops, and thanks. Wrong dup, but I'm sure that this question has been asked a gazillion times, and I do criticize the OP for terrible effort at first searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `string.matches` function to check for whether a string contains at-least one digit or not.

```
string.matches("\\D+");
```

This will return `true` for the strings which won't contain any single digit. `\\D` matches any non-digit character. So, `\\D+` matches one or more non-digit characters. By passing it to `matches` method, it would apply the regex against the whole string.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qQ0tF3/1)

Comment: if you want to match empty string also then change `+` in the above regex to `*`

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. Could you please tell  me why the double slash (\\) before the D?

Comment: In java you need to escape the backslash in the actual regex one more time, so that it would be treated as regex otherwise it would be treated like an escape sequence.